# Partition Mount Point "/"

Tags: partitioning

I am new to ubuntu, and I installed it following one tutorial. In the tutorial it says it is enough to give "/" 30 GiB. However, now my "/" is 60% occupied. Is this normal? Should I give more space to it?

I reinstalled ubuntu once, I am guessing if this caused that high occupation.

[image: My Partition]

Comment: 30Gb may-or-may-not be very much...depending upon what you want to use your system for and what else you might want to install, Not sure why you believe a reinstall would take extra space...unless you reinstalled some weird way. Also not sure why you believe you need a swap partition at all, or a separate /home. I don't know who wrote your tutorial, but it seems unnecessarily complicated. The Ubuntu installer defaults are sane and will give a nice general-use system for most new users. That's why the defaults are set that way.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Your actual usage will dictate the space requirements (eg. the more software you want to install, the more disk space required; and when you release-upgrade you'll of course need space unless you want to *nuke&install*). The wiki currently suggests 25gb so you've allocated more than that, I work on 32gb - but what you'll do with it will dictate your actual requirements

Comment: Thank you all very much for your explanation. Now I understand more about partition.

Comment: So you want to know if re-installation kept some previous install's clutter or not. It supposed not to but if you really do a reinstall on a dedicated partition for Ubuntu root (/) you should also make sure that the ***format partition*** option is checked (It's the default in general).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out which directories/files that are occupying most of the drive space in your root partition.

- It helps if you tell us how you did the re-installation.

  - Is there a (big) swapfile?
  - Are there files/directories left from previous installations?
  - Have you installed some huge program packages?
- You can try the following commands to identify the directories/files that are occupying most of the drive space,

  ```
  sudo find / -maxdepth 3 -exec du -hs {} \; |sort -h
  ```

  or the long command line (that you can copy and paste, and modify `lines=30` if you want to see another number of lines with big directories/files)

  ```
  lines=30;for i in $(LANG=C df|grep '^/dev/'|tr -s ' ' ' '|cut -d ' ' -f 6-);do echo "--- This is the viewer 'less', quit with 'q' ---";sudo du "$i" -hx|sort -rh|head -n$lines;done|less
  ```

  and the graphical program  (you may have to install it)

  ```
  baobab
  ```

  or to see what a regular user cannot see

  ```
  sudo -H baobab
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much, this really helps.with the command baobab I can see that Mathematica and texlive occupies more than 14 GiB of my space. It seems nothing is abnormal.

Comment: @Houshou, I'm glad I could help you find what is occupying drive space in your root partition :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have installed with a 30 GB root partition (`/`, sdb6) for the system files, and a separate 261 GB partition for `home` (sdb5). In such setup, all your user data will go into the separate home partition, which provides plenty space.

Ubuntu typically needs no more than 10-12 GB for system files (`/`). 30 GB is plenty for a system partition if you have a separate home partition.

You are now at 18 GB, which is relatively much. This could be due to many old kernels still remaining on the system, or on large log files. Or perhaps other than Ubuntu system files have been put at some time on that partition 30 GB for a separate home partition is plenty. You may want to examine the contents of that partition sdb6 using a tool such as Disk Usage Analyzer to see what might be causing this larger disk space use.

It might be wise to do that from a live session, started from an installation CD or USB. Perhaps, some old user data is present in the /home folder on the system partition sdb6. Since currently, your separate /home (sdb5) partition is mounted on that folder, the contents that might be in there are currently obscured. When you work from a live session, nothing will be mounted on the folders of your system partition (sdb6).

Answer (score -1):

Look "/" is called root partition in linux and all files are stored under it.  You can choose size by expecting what you want to do in ubuntu

Comment: Thank you. May I think in this way  that if I want to install more applications I should give more space to "/"?

Comment: Applications generally are not the issue, but what data you want to store in /home is. If you start storing a lot of files or large files and all you have is / (root) then 25 or 30GB may not be enough. Then either large / or separate /home and/or data partitions may make sense. But it comes down to each user and his own requirements and use.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?? A new installation of 18.04 LTS should not take up more than 10GB in root and home partitions. You've already used about 18GB, which if not including data files is a lot of space used.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 18.04. I don't think I have so many data files since I just installed it 2 days ago. Now after I installed a full version of texlive, it beomes 24 GiB used.

Comment: I don't know what browser you use. But with Firefox large numbers of cache files accumulate in your Home folder. Depending on frequency of browsing these can soon amount to GB in volume if not removed. That would be my first place to look. Scan through your `home/username/.cache folder`.